# How to convert String to int and call method on it?

Tags: java, integer, string-parsing

I have tried to convert my `String` to an `int` but my code keeps crashing.

The code is as follows:

```
String age = getAge();
CalculateDaysSinceBirth((int) age);
```

But I get a `NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Integer.valueOf(age)` insted of `(int) age`

Comment: It helped me, thanks.

Comment: The above answer will cause an exception if the string cannot be parsed to an int. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java for a more in depth answer.